Why am I getting an error trying to upload a file to a REST endpoint using .http files in Visual Studio 2022
I have the following code in a .http file.
@fileName = C:/MyFile.txt

POST {{baseUrl}}/api/endpoint
Authorization: Bearer {{adminToken}}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyFormBoundary

--MyFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/{{fileName}}"

< {{fileName}}
--MyFormBoundary--

When I send this request using the VS Code Rest Client extension, the request is processed by the REST API as expected.  When I try to send the request using Visual Studio 2022 (17.9.5) I get the error "Failed to read the request form. Invalid header line: --MyFormBoundary--".
Is there a bug with Visual Studio, or do I have to do something extra to get it to work with VS?
